# Using Apache2.4.33 (Linux/SUSE), how does one setup a URL to point directly to a service port without an object

Tags: apache-2.4

I have searched, and thought that I might have the answers from either of these two posts:

- [ProxyPass: Redirect directory URL to non-standard
  port](https://serverfault.com/questions/246445/how-do-i-create-virtual-hosts-for-different-ports-on-apache)
- [How do I create Virtual Hosts for Different Ports on
  Apache?](https://serverfault.com/questions/246445/how-do-i-create-virtual-hosts-for-different-ports-on-apache)

However, those options haven't worked for me, and I think it is because I am trying to redirect to something that isn't an object in the web directory, but it is just a game service running on a port.

Specifically: I want a URL, like domain.com/gameService, to redirect to the specific port on the server, like domain.com:gameServicePort. In the example, domain.com IS on DNS and I can reach the server itself, "gameService" is the placeholder for the service name, and "gameServicePort" is the placeholder for the port that the service is running on.

**Update 1**

Based on [this link](https://serverfault.com/questions/799012/dynmap-throu-mod-proxy-on-a-external-webserver) provided by @Orphan below, I have now tried both of the following as part of my vhost.conf, but to no avail - I still keep getting the 404 error of "Object not found!":

```
    <Location "/7dtd/">
      ProxyRequests off
      ProxyPass "http://127.0.0.1:8080/"
    </Location>
```

and

```
    NameVirtualHost *:80
    <VirtualHost *:80>
      ProxyRequests off
      ProxyPass "/7dtd" http://127.0.0.1:8080/
      ProxyPassReverse "/7dtd" http://127.0.0.1:8080/
    </VirtualHost>
```

I have also attempted to learn from [the documentation itself](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/reverse_proxy.html) in reference to Gerald Schneider's comment below, but also have had no such luck.

Obviously, I am doing something wrong or just plain missing something, but I'm just not seeing it. Please be direct with me as the documentation seems unclear to me...

Thank you for any assistance!

Comment: The search term you are looking for is `reverse proxy`

Comment: I can just refer to this question https://serverfault.com/questions/799012/dynmap-throu-mod-proxy-on-a-external-webserver

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the problem was in syntax (perhaps). The following is exactly what I have in my 7dtd.conf file at the time of this posting (tabs and all).

```
ProxyRequests off
ProxyPass   "/7dtd/cpnl"    http://localhost:8080/

ProxyPassReverse    "/7dtd/cpnl"    http://localhost:8080/
```